# Getting syntax error while using command line output

Tags: command-line-interface

I am trying to use command to store the output with the below script

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT=${ls -al}
echo "$OUTPUT"
```

when I am trying to execute I am getting the below syntax error:

```
(localhost)$ ./subst.sh
./subst.sh: line 3: ${ls -al}: bad substitution
```

What is the wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the Curly braces and use Parenthesis because

Curly braces are used for variable change and for command substitution you need to use Parenthesis in your script as below

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT=$(ls -al)
echo "$OUTPUT"
```